# Simple query in MSSQL. SELECT

Tags: sql-server, select

I'm an elementary user of MSSQL. I cannot finish my query properly. It should be a simple problem.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT Pass_in_trip.date, Count(date) as numbOfPassengers
From Pass_in_trip, Trip
WHERE (Trip.trip_no = Pass_in_trip.trip_no AND Trip.town_from='Rostov')
Group BY date
HAVING COUNT(date) = 3
```

This way it does work. But I want to compare COUNT(date) with MAX(COUNT(date)) and then I get a problem:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: [Use explicit joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) to start with

Comment: You're not describing your problem correctly. What would max(count()) do? Since you have a group by, the count is just one value, and taking max of it, would still be the same number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what you are looking for.

A common table expression will help avoid having to repeat the query.

```
WITH cte as
  (
    SELECT Pass_in_trip.date, Count(date) as numbOfPassengers
    FROM Pass_in_trip
    INNER JOIN Trip 
       ON Trip.trip_no = Pass_in_trip.trip_no
    WHERE Trip.town_from='Rostov'
    GROUP BY date
  )
SELECT date, numbOfPassengers
FROM cte
WHERE numbOfPassengers = (SELECT MAX(numbOfPassengers) FROM cte)
```